# Flex data grid: Check whether item renderer displays last row in grid

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm currently working with the OLAPDataGrid component and got stuck at a relatively simple task: I want to style the last row of the grid differently from the rest, so my cell item renderer needs to know whether he's rendering the last row with content in the overall grid, including those rows currently not rendered because they are outside the visible grid space. AdvancedGridListData's rowIndex property only gets me the row index of the renderer relative to the range of visible grid rows, i.e. when I scroll down the grid, a data item with an index greater than 0 gets the rpw index = 0.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a hack more than anything else but you can add a property to the dataprovider that marks it as the last row. Then you can reference that property in the item renderer and style the row accordingly.

Say your dp is an arraycollection...

```
dp.getItemAt(dp.length-1).isLastRow = true;
```

Or XMLListCollection

```
dp.getItemAt(dp.length - 1).@isLastRow = true;
```

The only thing you have to be concerned with is that this item remains last all the time. You can probably sort it by some value and then set this property.

Then in your item renderer you'll have something like this:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    if(data.isLastRow)
    {
        //Style the item renderer here
    }
    else if(data.@isLastRow.toString() == "true")
    {
        //XMLListCollection... Style the item renderer here
    }
}
```

Like I said, there may be an easier way and this may be a hack. Please post a better solution here (if you find one) for future reference.

Thanks,

-Vic

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is part of the original DataVisualization components, which means that it should expose a styleFunction. There is extensive documentation on how to create and use a styleFunction in the AdvanceDataGrid docs.